# How to calculate inverse of quaternion?

Tags: unity, quaternion

I would like to calculate

```
Quaternion.Inverse(Vector3(45,85,96));
```

but I got error message

```
Expression denotes a `type', where a `variable', `value' or `method group' was expected
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to a minor typographic error: `new Vector3(...)`

Comment: @Draco18s there's a little more going on here than that, so I wrote up a quick answer to explain.

Comment: Good point. Though correcting the one simple error would have lead to a second simple error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be trying to write

```
Quaternion.Inverse(Quaternion.Euler(45, 85, 96));
```

Although in a shader language like hlsl you can just write `float3(45, 85, 96)` to get a vector, in C# the *type* `Vector3` is different from the *constructor method* used to create one. When you just write `Vector3`, you're referring to the type, but when you write `new Vector3(...)`, you're calling its constructor to make a new instance of the type. That's why you get the error:

> Expression denotes a 'type', where a 'variable', 'value' or 'method group' was expected

But, that's not the full problem here. The `Quaternion.Inverse()` method wants a `Quaternion` as its argument, not a `Vector3`, so even using the correct syntax to create a `new Vector3` instance, it's still going to complain that you're giving it the wrong ingredient.

Assuming that the three components of this vector are actually three Euler angles describing an orientation, you can create a `Quaternion` that describes that same orientation using [the factory method `Quaternion.Euler()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html)